# Search for documents matching all terms in a nested array Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am learning to use Elasticsearch as a basic recommender engine.
My elasticsearch document contains records with nested entities as follows

```
PUT recs/user/1
{
  "name" : "Brad Pitt",
  "movies_liked": [
    {
      "name": "Forrest Gump",
      "score": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Terminator",
      "score": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Rambo",
      "score": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Rocky",
      "score": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Good Will Hunting",
      "score": 2
    }
  ]
}

PUT recs/user/2
{
  "name" : "Tom Cruise",
  "movies_liked": [
    {
      "name": "Forrest Gump",
      "score": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Terminator",
      "score": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Rocky IV",
      "score": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Rocky",
      "score": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Rocky II",
      "score": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Predator",
      "score": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to search for users who specifically like "Forrest Gump","Terminator" and "Rambo".

I have used a nested query which currently looks like this

```
POST recs/user/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "movies_liked",
      "query": {
        "terms": {
          "movies_liked.name": ["Forrest Gump","Terminator","Rambo"]

          }
        }

    }
  }
}
```

However when I execute this search, I expected to see only the first record which has all the required terms, but in the results I am getting both the records. In the second record the user clearly does not have "Rambo" in his liked list. I understand that this query is doing an "OR" operation with the given terms, How do I tweak this query to do an "AND" operation so that only the records having all the terms get matched?

Comment: Try the [terms query set](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html) and specify a value for the minimum_should_match_field.

Comment: @harishkb Thanks for the quick reply, I'll check it out and update.

Comment: What version of elasticsearch are you using, what's the mapping of your index?

Comment: @alkis Elasticsearch 6.1     mapping : `{
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "standard",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "movies_liked": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "score": {
              "type": "double"
            }
          }
        },
        "required_matches": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Just an update terms query seems to be doing the same thing as OR, also the documentation for terms query seems sparse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I tweak this query to do an "AND" operation so that only the records having all the terms get matched?

By using a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-bool-query.html):

```
POST recs/user/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "movies_liked",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "movies_liked.name": [
                        "Forrest Gump"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "movies_liked",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "movies_liked.name": [
                        "Terminator"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "movies_liked",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "movies_liked.name": [
                        "Rambo"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `bool` wraps around several `nested` queries, not the other way around. It is important because the scope of a `nested` query is the nested document, because it basically a [hidden separate object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html).

Hope that helps!